TTabControl tabs that have a "circle" to show "changed" and a [x] close button
Is there any easy way to do Delphi IDE-like tabs in Firemonkey without inheriting TTabControl?

a "filled circle" when the content of that tab is changed (even if tab is not active)
show an [X] only on the Active Tab (but if TTabItem contents are changed, then it shows "filled circle")

I saw Create run time TTabItem , firemonkey but the code seems a bit complicated.
Where should I start looking at it from? OnPaint event?

I'd try a 3rd party component, e.g. TRzTabConrol. I think it is included in recent Delphis.

@UliGerhardt: for Firemonkey?

Oops, sorry, read the question the wrong way.

IMHO, you should use a Custom Style.

Adding a filled circle to style should be easy then
Here is a sample of how I use this, "simulating a MDI or Docking app"
procedure TMain.btnParametresClick(Sender: TObject);
var  F : TFormParam;
     ATabItem : TTabItem;
begin
// si existe déjà
if Liste.ContainsKey('Parametres')
  then begin
    TabControl1.ActiveTab:=IndexTab('Paramètres');
  end
else begin
// si non créé
  F:=TFormParam.Create(Self);
  ATabItem:=TabControl1.Add();
  // ajout à la liste
  Liste.Add('Parametres',F);
  ATabItem.Text:='Paramètres';
  ATabItem.StyleLookup:='CloseTabItem';
  TButton(ATabItem.FindStyleResource('btnCloseTab')).OnClick:=CloseTab;
  TButton(ATabItem.FindStyleResource('btnCloseTab')).TagObject:=ATabItem;
  TButton(ATabItem.FindStyleResource('btnCloseTab')).TagString:='Parametres';
  ATabItem.AddObject(F.MainLayout);
  TabControl1.TabIndex:=TabControl1.TabCount-1; // onglet actif=nouvelle fenêtre
end;
Multiview1.HideMaster;
end;

but interacting with the button is a bit tricky.
To close my form related tab I use this
procedure TMain.CloseTab(Sender: TObject);
var F : TForm;
begin
 if not Datas.PeutFermer then Exit;

 if TabControl1.TabIndex=TabControl1.TabCount-1 then TabControl1.Previous else TabControl1.Next;

 if Liste.TryGetValue(TButton(Sender).TagString,F) then
   F.Close;

 TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
         TButton(Sender).TagObject.DisposeOf;
         if TabControl1.TabIndex>TabControl1.TabCount-1
           then TabControl1.TabIndex:=TabControl1.TabCount-1
        end);
    end);
 Liste.Remove(TButton(Sender).TagString);
end; 


Thanks! will check it out. meanwhile if anyone has any non-style solutions, let me know.
